# Authentik how to setup tenants

Tags: docker, authentication, multi-tenant

I'm using Authentik and have it working with services/providers.

I have a few different clients and would like to use the tenancy option.
My questions are

1. Does each tenant have to be a different outpost (and thus running container)
2. Can't I just create multiple tenants in my default installation?
3. Can I add users/groups specific to a tenant?

Thanks